# Entity Framework: Mapping Existing Tables w/ no Referential Integrity

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

In this scenario, I have an existing database with three models:

`Address`, which has a 'AddressId', 'ParentId', 'City', 'State', etc

`Person`, which has a 'PersonId', 'Name', etc.

`Company`, which has a 'CompanyId', 'Name', etc.

Because `Address` can contain rows for more models than just one table, there's no foreign key; the `Address` column 'ParentId' would contain either a 'PersonId' or 'CompanyId'.

To generate my `DbContext`, I used Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 2.  Due to the lack of referential integrity, the classes it generated for `Person` and `Company` do not contain a collection of addresses like they should.

How would I go about altering those classes to add in this "Addresses" property, and ensure it's mapped to the Address table correctly?

At the moment I'm doing something like this; I'd rather have the context map it if possible:

```
public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses
{
   get 
   {
       IEnumerable<Address> addresses = null;
       using(MyDb db = new MyDb())
       {
            addresses = db.Addresses.Where(a => a.ParentId == this.PersonId)
       }

       return addresses;
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does your address table have a discriminator column?  How do you determine if it's a person or company address?

Comment: Nope; there's no way of telling from just looking at the row

Comment: What if a company and a person have the same id? How would you know which is the parent of the address?

Comment: All ids in this scenario are guids; that shouldn't happen

Comment: Is there a reason you didn't just add an AddressId to both the Person and Company tables, and keys to the Address table?  Then EF would deal with everything for you.

Comment: This is an existing application.  Also, there could be multiple addresses per person or company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, you should add an unique id to the Address table and then store that id with the entity that it belongs to, whether it be a person, company, vendor etc.

If you can't because of the multiple address scenario, then you could create a new table AddressXRef table that stores the GUID's of the entities (vendor, person, company etc), and the GUID of the address; so every entity could have multiple address and EF will be quite happy with this setup as there will be keys all around.

(I'd also want some sort of address type indicator on the Xref table so I knew what kind of address it was, mailing, shipping, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Create partial classes for both `Company` and `Person` which have that property you have created in it.

```
public partial class Company
{
   public IEnumerable<Address> Addresses { ... }
}
```